# Date comparison in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Here Date is in the format yy-mm-dd hr:min:sec where as $this->get('on') is in the format yy-mm-dd . so now how to compare these two values?

```
function customer_get()
{
        $this->db->select('user_id,first_name,last_name,email');
        $this->db->from('customers');
        $this->db->join('orders', 'user_id = customer_user_id','inner');
        $array = array('Date' => $this->get('on'));
        $this->db->where($array);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query)
        {
                $this->response($query->result(),200);
        }
        else
        {
                $this->response(NULL, 404);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is your yy-mm-dd hr:min:sec field is important with seconds also ....

Comment: Sir. Yes its important i want exact time and date for that table.  Is there any way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you'll want to format the date properly for your query:

```
function customer_get()
{

        $this->db->select('user_id,first_name,last_name,email');
        $this->db->from('customers');
        $this->db->join('orders', 'user_id = customer_user_id','inner');
        $this->db->where('DATE(`Date`)', $this->get('on'), false);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query)
        {
                $this->response($query->result(),200);
        }
        else
        {
                $this->response(NULL, 404);
        }

}
```

Comment: $array = array('Date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($this->get('on'))));    can u please explain this  one ...

Comment: You have to convert the date to MySQL's datetime format for the query to work

Comment: Sir but Date is having both data as well as time where as this->get('on') [which is given as input] has only date. ...

Comment: Well, I've given you a bit of direction.  Can you solve it from here?

Comment: I tried but i am not able to solve it please can u suggest me any method to solve it